# Iterating over synchronized collection

Tags: java, multithreading, vector, synchronized

I asked here a question about iterating over a `Vector`, and I have been answered with some good solutions. But I read about another simpler way to do it. I would like to know if it is good solution.

```
synchronized(mapItems) {
    Iterator<MapItem> iterator = mapItems.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
        iterator.next().draw(g);
}
```

mapItems is a synchronized collection: Vector. Is that make the iterating over the `Vector` safe from `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: have you got any correct answer to accept??

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will make it safe from `ConcurrentModificationException` at the expense of everything essentially being single-threaded.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe that this will prevent a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  You are synchronizing on the `Vector`.  All methods on `Vector` that modify it are also `synchronized`, which means that they would also lock on that same object.  So no other thread could change the `Vector` while you're iterating over it.

Also, you are not modifying the `Vector` yourself while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply synchronizing the entire collection would not prevent a ConcurrentModificationException.  This will still throw a CME

```
synchronized(mapItems) {
   for(MapItem item : mapsItems){
      mapItems.add(new MapItem());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a ReadWriteLock.

For processes which iterate over the list without modifying its contents, get a read lock on the shared ReentrantReadWriteLock. This allows multiple threads to have read access to the lock.

For processes which will modify the list, acquire the write lock on the shared lock. This will prevent all other threads from accessing the list (even read-only) until you release the write lock.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that make the iterating over the Vector safe from
>   ConcurrentModificationException?

**YES** It makes the iterating over Vector safe from `ConcurrentModificationException`.If it is not synchronized then in that case , if you are accessing the Vector via various threads and some other Thread is  structurally modifying the Vector at any time after the iterator is created , the iterator will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.
Consider running this code:

```
import java.util.*;
class VVector 
{
    static Vector<Integer> mapItems = new Vector<Integer>();
    static
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 200 ; i++)
        {
            mapItems.add(i);
        }
    }
    public static void readVector()
    {
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = mapItems.iterator();
        try
        {
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.print(iterator.next() + "\t");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();System.exit(0);}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        VVector v = new VVector();
        Thread th = new Thread( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while ( true )
                {
                    mapItems.add(345);
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == 100)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        th.start();
        v.readVector();

    }
}
```

At my system it is showing following output while execution:

```
0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
        at VVector.readVector(VVector.java:19)
        at VVector.main(VVector.java:38)
```

But on the other hand if you make the block of code containing `Iterator` to access that `Vector` synchronized using `mapItems` as lock , it will prevent the execution of other methods related to `Vector` until that `synchronized`  block is completed atomically .

Answer (score 0):

if we invoke add method inside while loop then throws exception.

```
synchronized(mapItems) {
    Iterator<MapItem> iterator = mapItems.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
        iterator.next();
         mapItems.add("Something");  //  throws ConcurrentModificationException
}
```